# Counting beginning character of each word in python

Tags: python, count

I am wanting to return the number of times certain letters are used to begin words in a .txt file. For instance, "stop talking tim" would have a s = 1 and t = 2 for the first character counts. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If you have, please show your code. Explain what is not working out for you.

Comment: Edit your question and put that code in there and format it properly, please.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started, we were all beginners once:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "stop talking tim"
words = s.split()
letters = [w[0] for w in words]
print Counter(letters)
```

Gives:

```
Counter({'t': 2, 's': 1})
```